# Mongo C# Driver and ObjectID JSON String Format

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

Is it possible to force the `JsonWriterSettings` to output the `ObjectID` as

```
{ "id" : "522100a417b86c8254fd4a06" }
```

instead of

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "522100a417b86c8254fd4a06" }
```

I know I could write my own parser, but for the sake of code maintenance, I would like to find away to possibly override the `Mongo JsonWriterSettings`.

If this is possible, what classes/Interfaces should I override?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend changing the way the deserialization is done. It's most likely written in a way that makes sense for the object structure. Instead I'd model my object I'm serializing to match the format. namespace object { class id { oid id; } class oid { String id } }. Something like that.

Answer (score 6):

If you're OK with using MongoDB C# attributes or the Mapper, then you can do something like this:

```
public class Order {
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

That way, you can refer to the type as a string normally (including serialization), but when MongoDB serializes it, etc., it's internally treated as an ObjectId. Here's using the class map technique:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Order>(cm => {
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.SetIdMember(cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.Id);
    cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.Id)
       .SetRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use JSON.NET instead it's easy to add a `JsonConverter` that converts `ObjectId` values to strings and vice-versa.

In ASP.NET WebAPI you can then add this to the default set of converters at `Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters`

Answer (score 0):

I am using MongoDB.Driver with version 2.15.1 and for me is working this simple solution:

```
public class Order {
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

You do not have to specify attribute [BsonId] if the property name is "Id" The driver uses naming conventions.